# Windows 10 upgrade downloaded but not restarted

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was trying to upgrade my windows 10 version 1909 to 20H2 using the [Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). The download was successful after a (really) long time and showed this:

[Img](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1im2p6ZKL6QQYqb8Xxcm9_S6mfpDgIG0T/view?usp=drivesdk)

I chose to restart later and turned off the PC. But now when I open the Update Assistant, it starts verifying the update and then shows the same things as before(your update is getting ready).

Any help? Has it started to download the update all over again?

Edit: After 4 hours, I've finally got a prompt to restart. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The message "Your update is ready" means that the update was downloaded to your computer
and is ready to be installed.

Sometimes more updates are downloaded, if they have become available since the time
you have postponed it, but the major part should already been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should not shut down in the middle of an update like this. New versions of Windows make this plainer. Sometimes an update will get stuck and the only option is to shut down.

However it will pick up where it left off. I have seen that happen on customer machines. My own Insider machine had an issue and I had to force it off. It picked up where it left off.

If this does not work, you may need to start the update again.

Comment: I thought that download and installation happen independently of each other and turning off in between them won't cause any issue. But unfortunately, it didn't pick up where it had left.

Comment: There is no hard and fast procedure.  You may in this case, restart the update.